# Simulate a thermistor to fake temperature readings in heater

Tags: potentiometer, thermistor, heater

**What I want to do**

Control an old heater to avoid running during hours where kWh is expensive. Bonus: Getting a more even inside temperature.

**How I plan to achieve this**

I know there is a product where I live, which is capable of controlling old heaters like mine. The way it does this is by replacing the existing outside temperature sensor to provide it fake readings. E.g. a higher outside temperature value to trick heater into avoid starting. I also know that my heater uses a 150 ohm NTC thermistor, however I don't know what the internals of the heater, the part which reads values, look like.

Now, the product is expensive and doing more than I need and so I thought I could solve this myself. Knowing when I need heat and when I don't need heat is not a problem. My problem is understanding what I need to simulate the thermistor. With my limited knowledge of electronics, I can only come up with using a digital potentiometer (+ Raspberry Pi Pico or similar).

**My problem**

I did some calculation on NTC thermistors and came to the conclusion that, if I want to be able to simulate every °C between -20 and +30 then I would need a digital pot with a resolution down to 5 ohm per step. The thermistor ranges from 123 ohm (30°C) to 1255 ohm (-20°C). However, I fail to find a digital potentiometer that supports this. Maybe I could go with [MCP4251](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/MCP4251#document-table) and accept that I would lack resolution on the upper end. If my understanding is correct I would lack precision as the simulated temperature goes over 10°C: 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 23, 27, 30°C .

**My questions**

Would it make sense to simulate the thermistor using a chip like MCP4251 and RPI Pico?

Is there a better suited digital pot that would give me better resolution in my range (100 - 1500 ohm)?

Are there other, better ways to achieve what I want?

**Appendix**

[MCP4251](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/MCP4251#document-table)

[My thermistor calculations](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dA6Aa1Qh7AtfLZBsgO4TlNQNOJroUqap76TA2cLRoKI/edit?usp=sharing)

[Heater manual in Swedish, see page 56 terminal block G11, G12](https://ctc.se/file-download/6588f57ac5fd4208d76cba6e15eb7274.pdf)

Comment: Just put a heating element right near the thermistor. Turn it on when you want to supress the heater.

Comment: Anything wrong with a timer switch?

Comment: I want relatively fine control over the “thermistor” so that I can account for not only expensive hours but also solar radiation to get a more even indoor temp. Heating element is not an alternative I’m considering.

Comment: As for the switch. The heater is three phase and also controls heating tap water which I don’t want to stop it from doing.

Comment: You can also just figure out how the device is reading the thermistor, then  based on that do something compatible. For example, one side of the thermistor is probably either grounded or connected to some positive power rail. That should be easy to figure out. You could probably put a switched resistor network in place of the thermistor, and use IO signals from your pi to select 1 of N values where N is a power of 2, and the number of IO signals used is log base 2 (N).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the MCP4251 and similar digital devices is that the potentiometer signals must be within the supply rails, as the datasheet says "The voltage on terminal A must be between VSS and VDD.", and likewise for terminal B.

If you are connecting to unknown circuitry in the heater, it is difficult to be sure that your digital pot isn't trying to pull the thermistor lines outside their correct working voltage with respect to ground, and conversely, that the heater isn't pulling the lines outside the range allowed by the potentiometer - it is all a bit risky, if you don't know what circuitry you are controlling.

So for safety reasons, I think you need to have a galvanically isolated output, which is quite complicated for an analog signal, but is quite easy for a digital signal - an optocoupler across the thermistor can be used to simulate a high temperature, causing the heater to switch off.

So I'd put an opto across the thermistor, and use that as an on-off control, with a separate temperature sensor being used to decide whether the heater should be on or off. This arrangement has the additional advantage that if your new controller circuitry is powered down, then the opto will go high-resistance, and the heater will behave as before.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but just measuring voltage over these terminals in the heater is not helping?

Comment: As for the optocoupler. Then heater would see either regular thermistor OR my own resistor of, let’s say, 100 Ohm (30C ish), correct? It’s definitely more rough than being able to control more precisely but perhaps it’s enough for my application.

Comment: You need to measure the voltage across the thermistor terminals, and most importantly, the voltage with respect to ground, both AC and DC. You can't just assume that one side of the thermistor is grounded, is may be connected to any part of the heater control circuitry, and that circuitry itself may or may not be grounded. I'm being over-cautious, but you do mention that the equipment is expensive, and I'm assuming that you don't want any risk of damaging it.

Comment: I did mean that the other product on market which controls legacy heater this way is expensive. But you are nevertheless correct in that the heater itself is quite expensive and definitely not something I want to damage.